# Which kind of background music playing strategy should I choose after the 1607 Update?

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, background-audio

I starting developing a music app since July, but after Windows 10 Update 1607 (a.k.a Redstone Update), the app can go into background easily, which makes background playing much easier. But since I want to reserve the application's compatibility in older version of Windows 10, should I use the old strategy, which has a background audio task? Do those new APIs compatible with older platform like 10240 and 10586?

[The new strategy here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio)
[The old strategy here (Though in Chinese)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio)

Addition: My app needs to get the audio address and the audio content from the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to support the older Windows 10 builds (10240, 10586) you must implement the background audio with the old background task approach, because the new API is not available for the older builds.

In the ideal world every Windows 10 device will be updated to any update within 6 month. Of course we are not in the ideal world unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, and in fact I felt somewhat awful that in order to remain compatible, the new APIs should never be considered .. :<